# Using HTTP protocol, is there a possibility to define additional metatdata that will be associated to files being downloaded?

Tags: http, http-headers, filesystems, webserver

Using the `HTTP protocol`, is there a possibility to define additional `metadata` or `attributes` (eg : an ID, a key) that will be associated to a file once a user has download it ?

What i have in mind : i need to setup a document management tool, and i'd like to "stamp documents" (aka files) downloaded by users. Once uploaded back (eg : new version) i'd like to easily identify which document it is (by using something else than the filename, which can be easily changed).

Is this possible ? (I am not sure it is, because of confidentiality and security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a full control over the http download agent/client? If yes you can check [File Fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29). And for NTFS it's called alternative stream.